# Объединение глифов в шрифте (или SVG в веб-шрифт)

Tags: css, svg, шрифты

Всем привет!

Стоит задача создать веб-шрифт из EPS-файлов. Получить нормальные SVG после некоторой корректировки получилось, но с конвертированием в веб-шрифт возникла проблема.

Вручную перерисовывать глифы нет ни времени, ни желанию, поэтому пробую онлайн-средства. Правильно сделать такое конвертирование смог лишь IcoMoon, однако он, по какой-то причине, разделил каждый глиф на несколько. То есть вместо цельного символа я получил "наборы".

Очевидно, подобный CSS выдаёт каждую часть иконки (глифа) друг за другом, как обычный текст: `i.public-pools:before {content: '\e900\e901';}`

То есть мне нужно или с помощью CSS показать все глифы как бы друг на друге, или объединить глифы в самом шрифте. Буду рад, если подскажите название программы, умеющей это делать, или какой-нибудь CSS-хак.

P. S.: на крайний случай, конечно, можно вставить иконки как SVG или даже как обычные картинки, но очень не хотелось бы так делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что иконки состоят из нескольких контуров.
Необходимо в любом векторном редакторе объединить кривые в одну иконку

Пример в Adobe Illustrator:
[image: Объединение контура Adobe Illustrator]